# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "add"

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans

Hello I maded a web service with odd or even and when i maked the client for that webservice in netbeans i had this error.
The web service here :

```
@WebService(serviceName = "Par_Impar")
public class Par_Impar {

/**
 * Web service operation
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "operation")
public String operation(@WebParam(name = "val") int val) {
   if(val%2!=0){
       //daca reminder-ul nu este 0 este impar
       return("IMPAR");
   }
   else {
       //daca reminder-ul este 0 atunci este par
       return("PAR");
   }
}

}
```

The index.jsp :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PAGINA JSP</title>   
</head>
<body>
    <form action="action.jsp" method="post"<br/>
          Introdu numarul :<input type="text" name="nr"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Testeaza"/>
</form>

</body>
```

The action.jsp :

```
<%-- 
Document   : action
Created on : Apr 27, 2013, 5:28:45 PM
Author     : ARB
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
<%-- start web service invocation --%><hr/>
<%
String add=request.getParameter("numar");
int aa=Integer.parseInt("add");
try {
mypack.ParImpar_Service service = new mypack.ParImpar_Service();
mypack.ParImpar port = service.getParImparPort();
 // TODO initialize WS operation arguments here
int val=aa;
    // TODO process result here
java.lang.String result = port.operation(aa);
out.println("Result = "+result);
} catch (Exception ex) {
// TODO handle custom exceptions here
}
%>
<%-- end web service invocation --%><hr/>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me. Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

```
int aa=Integer.parseInt("add");
```

Above line should be:

```
int aa=Integer.parseInt(add);
```

[parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

> Parses the string argument as a signed integer in the radix specified
> by the second argument. The characters in the string must all be
> digits of the specified radix (as determined by whether
> Character.digit(char, int) returns a nonnegative value), except that
> the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to
> indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to
> indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is returned.
>
> ***An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the
> following situations occurs:***
>
> 1. The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.
> 2. The radix is either smaller than Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than
>    Character.MAX_RADIX.
> 3. Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix,
>    except that the first character may be a minus sign '-' ('\u002D')
>    or plus sign '+' ('\u002B') provided that the string is longer than
>    length 1.
> 4. The value represented by the string is not a value of type int.

Comment: I tryed to put int aa=Integer.parseInt(add); and that's all i've done, because I am new in this and I need to learn alot. Now when I put a number and press the submit button to start the web service the result is like this : java.lang.NumberFormatException: null. Can you show me where an what to modify ? Thanks alot for the answers ! I appreciate what you are doing. Thanks again !

Comment: @AndreiR.Beraru I think `request.getParameter("numar")` this method is returning `null` so you are getting that exception .

Answer (score 0):

From your index.jsp your are sending parameter named `nr` but on the action.jsp you are retrieving a parameter called `numar`. Since there is no such parameter in the request, you end up parsing null. What @Achintya said also applies.

Comment: Thanks alot ! I didn't saw that. Thank you all !